# Joining to same table and updating column on row match for multiple columns

Tags: postgresql

I have a single table (table_1) of schema below:

```
row_id      identifier   col1    col2    col3    col4    status
1           A            1       2       3       4      
2           A            2       3       4       5      
3           B            1       2       3       4
4           B            2       3       4       6
5           C            1       2       3       4
```

I want to join on `identifier = A` such that any rows with `identifier != A` but which match on values for `col1, col2, col3` and `col4` will update the `status` column with values for any matched ('`B,C`'), and another for mismatch (foo).

Note that the status column values need to update with the identifier(s) matched.

```
row_id      identifier   col1    col2    col3    col4    status
1           A            1       2       3       4       B,C
2           A            2       3       4       5       foo
3           B            1       2       3       4
4           B            2       3       4       6
5           C            1       2       3       4
```

I've used a single SELECT statement with multiple subqueries for each separate column to match to on 'A', but had to explicitly select other identifiers and resulted in errors.

Corrected row_id to show the primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a self-join and an aggregate function (`string_agg`) to aggregate the `identifier`s that are different from the current row as below.

The first and last lines initializes the `status` column to `NULL` and finalizes it to `foo` if it isn't assigned, respectively:

```
UPDATE table_1 t1 SET status = NULL;

UPDATE table_1 t1
SET status = (
  SELECT string_agg(t2.identifier,',') FROM table_1 t2
  WHERE t2.identifier != t1.identifier
    AND t1.col1 = t2.col1
    AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
    AND t1.col3 = t2.col3
    AND t1.col4 = t2.col4
);

UPDATE table_1 t1 SET status = 'foo' WHERE status  IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update test_table t1
inner join (
    select *, 
      (case 
         when status_value is null then 'foo'
         else status_value
         end) as to_update_status from
         (select *, group_concat(case
                                   when identifier='A' then null
                                   else identifier 
                                   end
                                 ) as status_value from test_table
            group by col1, col2, col3, col4) as t1 where identifier='A' 
      ) t2 on t1.row_id = t2.row_id 
          and t1.identifier=t2.identifier
          and t1.col1 = t2.col1
          and t1.col2 = t2.col2
          and t1.col3 = t2.col3
          and t1.col4 = t2.col4
  set t1.status = t2.to_update_status;
```

In the above query, test_table is the name of the table.

Consider changing the structure of your table. It should have a unique identifier.(From the name, the column `row_id` should be unique, but it is not in the data you provided, so I had to put 5 additional checks in the join query). If your row has a unique identifier, you could select just the `row_id` and `to_update_status` in the subquery and simply check the `row_id`

You should also have an index on `identifer` column and a multi-column index on `col1, col2, col3, col4`.